# I cannot sign the bin\Debug\Mainpaint.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2019, signtool

When I am trying to build my project, it failed and this message occurs.
[image]

Can you please help me? So I can rebuild my project again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't use a codesigning certificate. When your certificate only supports digital signatures, it won‘t work. How do you created the certificate?